# How to put two shapes in one object in Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape, tools

How to put multiple shapes into one object (without grouping , cloning , union and also merging the shapes of them) in Inkscape?
I mean something like this :
 
 [image]

*Note that the box in center is one "object" not a group

[svg sample file (artwork by `vicko` at https://www.pling.com/u/vicko/)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XRmDqj_nwtRX64_zL8DY-zdYk-fNlPCB/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't want to group the shapes?

Comment: I want to design a custom tooltip and the problem is that my compositor in KDE desktop environment in linux needs exactly one object to work with and when it parses the svg file , it only picks up the first occurrence with the name "tooltip-normal" and my custom tooltip is somewhat like the above picture which needs to be at least two objects in design.But actually the reason isn't a part of that question.

Comment: Inkscape aims to be strictly compliant to SVG standard, and a shape in SVG is an elementary object i.e. with one fill and one stroke. If this is suitable for you, you can perform an [uion](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Paths-Combining.html) on your shapes. Else, you must tweak your compositor and parse for groups or other SVG objects.

Comment: But in the above image I think the center box has two Fill and Strokes but its tag in the XML editor panel hasn't any child so it's just one object.Am I wrong about "two fill-and-strokes" or is it non-standard?

Comment: If you group the objects and name the group "tooltip-normal", then your tool will pick that element up? I think perhaps your question is not about inkscape, but about your KDE compositor.

Comment: In addition to the suggestion of Luciano, can you edit your question and add the SVG source of an object that is suitable for your KDE composer and another object that doesn't?

Comment: @Luciano Yeah that's the problem with the compositor but the image that I posted is from one of the themes that already works well for KDE.I've also tried grouping but the compositor picks up the first item in the group so my tooltip looks incomplete.

Comment: What exactly is this compositor you're using? Is there any documentation you could consult? it's starting to sound like a tech support question since you're using valid SVG and it's the tool that doesn't accept it. As Paolo said, can you compare it to a working SVG file?

Comment: @PaoloGibellini I added an example file that works well , and I want to create an effect like that "menuitem" button for "tooltip-normal".

Comment: @Luciano It's true that my compositor is terrible in that respect but I'm not here to improve that , I just want to know how can I create such a stuff in Inkscape since the image above contains what I want but I don't know the way to create that in one object.

Comment: I'm not able to answer to your question, because I have not enough information on the way the SVG file is used. Your buttons are mostly composed by 9 paths, each filled with a gradient, and each with an id whose name is related to its position, except the dark grey button, which has a group. But how the elements are picked by the composer is out of my control. If you wrote the compositor, you should know how to pick the elements, else I suggest you to ask to the programmer who wrote it.

Comment: Does it pick up clones or patterned objects?

Comment: @Moini My actual problem is that I want two fill and strokes in one object as seen in the image above but I don't know how to create that.Furthermore it seems non-standard.And the problem with clone is that when the compositor reads the cloned objects , then it is refered to the actual object which doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two kinds of labels that Inkscape uses.The first one that the standard SVG (and also my compositor) doesn't care is `inkscape:label`(and each time you rename an object in the `objects` panel in fact that would be changed and it's for internal use by inkscape itself) and the one that my compositor parses each time is `id` :

[image]

So there is no need to have two shapes in one object , just what I needed to do was to change the group's `id` to `tooltip-normal`.
And that works well :

[image]